# TSQL problem to calculate differences between two dates inside one table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

In MSSQL 2008 I have table and data which looks like this

```
create table #tempData
(user_id int,type varchar(10),ts datetime)

insert into #tempData
select 1,'ENTER','2011-01-30 15:00:00'
union all
select 1,'EXIT','2011-01-31 16:00:00'
union all
select 1,'ENTER','2011-02-1 18:00:00'
union all
select 1,'EXIT','2011-02-10 21:00:00'
union all
select 2,'ENTER','2011-01-10 21:00:00'
union all
select 2,'EXIT','2011-01-12 21:00:00'
union all
select 2,'ENTER','2011-01-13 01:00:00'
union all
select 2,'EXIT','2011-01-13 18:00:00'
--AND SO ON --
```

Now I trying to make query which is going to tell how long one user was inside according to last exit
something like

```
user_id,exited,time_in_hours
1,'2011-01-31 16:00:00',25 
1,'2011-02-10 21:00:00',219
2,'2011-01-12 21:00:00',48
2,'2011-01-13 18:00:00',17
```

Sorry if this BAD or ROUGE question and if this is not proper way to ask a question like this.
But I am stacked on this for while.

Comment: What should happen if user Enters but do not exits and following sequence continues. What is the assumption

Comment: Can sessions for the same user intersect?

Comment: There is should be something like SessionId to build relation between ENTER-EXIT entries. otherwise it would be a mess (and wrong!) to build such pairs - just follow row id incrementation principle

Comment: I didn't think yet about intersect of user data, First I want to get anything to start with it

Comment: `rouge` means red in french.  `rogue` is something or someone that doesn't conform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that

- same-user sessions do not intersect,
- there cannot be an EXIT record without the corresponding ENTER record,

you could try the following:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    user_id,
    type,
    ts,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, type ORDER BY ts)
  FROM #tempData
)
SELECT
  tx.user_id,
  exited = tx.ts,
  hours = DATEDIFF(HOUR, tn.ts, tx.ts)
FROM ranked tn
  INNER JOIN ranked tx ON tn.user_id = tx.user_id AND tn.rn = tx.rn
WHERE tn.type = 'ENTER'
  AND tx.type = 'EXIT'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using CTE's you can do

```
with
  exits as ( select [user_id],ts from #tempData where type='EXIT'),
  entries as ( select [user_id],ts from #tempData where type='ENTER'),
  result as (
select 
RANK() over (Partition by a.user_id,b.ts order by a.ts desc) as i,
a.[user_id],b.ts as 'Last Exited',DATEDIFF(hh,a.ts,b.ts) as [hours]
from
    entries a inner join exits b on b.[User_id]=a.[User_id] and a.ts<b.ts
  )

select user_id,[Last Exited],hours from result where i=1
```

This solution however assumes that there is always an exit record than that record always matches to the immediately preceeding entry record

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select a.usr,a.ts enter_date
,min(b.ts) exit_date, datediff(ss,a.ts,min(b.ts)) diff_in_sec
from tempData a
    join tempdata b on a.usr = b.usr and a.ts < b.ts
where a.type='enter' and b.type='exit'
group by a.usr,a.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT user_id, exitTable.ts AS exited, DATEDIFF(hour, exitTable.ts, enterTable.ts) AS time_in_hours
FROM yourTable enterTable
    INNER JOIN yourTable exitTable
        ON enterTable.user_id = exitTable.user_id
            and exitTable.ts > enterTable.ts
                    and exitTable.type = 'EXIT'
WHERE enterTable.type = 'ENTER'
    and entertable.ts = (SELECT MAX(ts) FROM yourTable WHERE yourTable.user_id = enterTable.user_id AND type = 'ENTER')
```

A word of explanation...

The WHERE clause will limit the rows to the last ENTER for each user_id.  The JOIN clause joins that row with the EXIT that has a time after the entrance.

Comment: how will this work...I think it will calc difference b/w '2011-01-30 15:00:00' and '2011-02-10 21:00:00' i.e. first row with last row of same user i.e. user id 1

Comment: This will exclude sessions that have not yet expired.

Comment: The WHERE clause limits the rows to the last "ENTER".  The JOIN clause limits joins up with the EXIT that is greater than the selected ENTER.

Comment: @Shantanu, instead of asking "how will this work" and saying "I think" you should **TRY** the code and see if it gets the results you are after.