# Capture start and end times for changes of state of a field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This is a variation of this question [T-SQL Start and end date times from a single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637935/t-sql-start-and-end-date-times-from-a-single-column) except the event states may have multiple on or off states without a matching opposite state.

The question is how do I capture the start and end dates for the first "on" and next "off".  In other words, capture the first COS (change of state) to "on" and the **first** COS to "off" for each item.  This would be used to calculate a total runtime for the item.

Source:

```
Item      EventDate               Event
A         2011-10-03 00:01:00     On
A         2011-10-03 00:01:15     On
B         2011-10-03 00:01:00     On
A         2011-10-03 00:02:00     Off
A         2011-10-03 00:02:01     Off
C         2011-10-03 00:01:00     On
B         2011-10-03 00:02:00     Off
A         2011-10-03 00:02:02     On      
C         2011-10-03 00:02:05     On
A         2011-10-03 00:02:07     Off
```

Output:

```
Item      Start                   End
A         2011-10-03 00:01:00     2011-10-03 00:02:00
A         2011-10-03 00:02:02     2011-10-03 00:02:07
B         2011-10-03 00:01:00     2011-10-03 00:02:00
C         2011-10-03 00:01:00     2011-10-03 00:02:05
```

Comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: Sorry, I posted this quickly yesterday.  This is for SQL 2008 or higher, so I would need an answer that would apply to SQL 2008.  This would operate on typically 5000 rows or less.

Comment: You know that Sql Server 2008 is only about a year away from final end of life, right? Soon it won't get any patches... even critical security updates. It's time to start the migration project to a more recent release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have SQL Server 2012 or later then you can use SQL Servers windowing function to get the desired results as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EventStates](
    [Item] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [EventDate] [varchar](19) NOT NULL,
    [Event] [varchar](3) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

INSERT [dbo].[EventStates] ([Item], [EventDate], [Event]) VALUES (N'A', N'2011-10-03 00:01:00', N'On')
INSERT [dbo].[EventStates] ([Item], [EventDate], [Event]) VALUES (N'A', N'2011-10-03 00:01:15', N'On')
INSERT [dbo].[EventStates] ([Item], [EventDate], [Event]) VALUES (N'B', N'2011-10-03 00:01:00', N'On')
INSERT [dbo].[EventStates] ([Item], [EventDate], [Event]) VALUES (N'A', N'2011-10-03 00:02:00', N'Off')
INSERT [dbo].[EventStates] ([Item], [EventDate], [Event]) VALUES (N'A', N'2011-10-03 00:02:01', N'Off')
INSERT [dbo].[EventStates] ([Item], [EventDate], [Event]) VALUES (N'C', N'2011-10-03 00:01:00', N'On')
INSERT [dbo].[EventStates] ([Item], [EventDate], [Event]) VALUES (N'B', N'2011-10-03 00:02:00', N'Off')
INSERT [dbo].[EventStates] ([Item], [EventDate], [Event]) VALUES (N'A', N'2011-10-03 00:02:02', N'On')
INSERT [dbo].[EventStates] ([Item], [EventDate], [Event]) VALUES (N'C', N'2011-10-03 00:02:05', N'On')
INSERT [dbo].[EventStates] ([Item], [EventDate], [Event]) VALUES (N'A', N'2011-10-03 00:02:07', N'Off')

GO

;WITH StateChange
AS
(
    SELECT   E.[Item]
            ,E.[EventDate]
            ,E.[Event]
            ,(  -- First determine if a state change to on has occurred.
                CASE
                    WHEN E.[Event] = 'On' AND LAG(E.[Event], 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY E.[Item] ORDER BY E.[EventDate] ASC) IS NULL THEN 1
                    WHEN E.[Event] = 'On' AND E.[Event] <> LAG(E.[Event], 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY E.[Item] ORDER BY E.[EventDate] ASC) THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END
             ) [StateChanged]
    FROM    EventStates E
), StateChangeGrouping
AS
(
    SELECT   [Item]
            ,[EventDate]
            ,[Event]
            ,[StateChanged]
            ,SUM([StateChanged]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Item] ORDER BY [EventDate] ASC) AS [GroupID]
    FROM    StateChange 
), StateChangeRanked
AS
(
    SELECT   [Item]
            ,[EventDate]
            ,[Event]
            ,[StateChanged]
            ,[GroupID]
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Item], GroupID, [Event] ORDER BY [EventDate]) AS TransitionRank
    FROM    StateChangeGrouping
)
SELECT      [Item]
            ,MIN([EventDate]) AS [Start]
            ,MAX([EventDate]) AS [End]
            ,[GroupID]
FROM        StateChangeRanked
WHERE       GroupID > 0 AND TransitionRank = 1
GROUP BY    [Item], GroupID
ORDER BY    [Item], [Start]
```

Below is an implementation for SQL Server 2008.

```
;WITH EventID
AS
(
    SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Item] ORDER BY [EventDate]) RowNr
            ,[Item]
            ,[EventDate]
            ,[Event] 
    FROM    [dbo].[EventStates]
), StateChange
AS
(
    SELECT  C.RowNr
            ,P.RowNr AS P_RowNr
            ,C.[Item]
            ,C.[EventDate]
            ,C.[Event] 
            ,P.[Event] AS P_Event
            ,(  -- First determine if a state change to on has occurred.
                CASE
                    WHEN C.[Event] = 'On' AND P.[Event] IS NULL THEN 1
                    WHEN C.[Event] = 'On' AND C.[Event] <> P.[Event] THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END
                ) [StateChanged]
    FROM    EventID C
    LEFT OUTER JOIN EventID P ON C.Item = P.Item AND C.RowNr = P.RowNr + 1
), StateChangeGrouping
AS
(
    SELECT   ST1.[Item]
            ,ST1.[EventDate]
            ,ST1.[Event]
            ,ST1.[StateChanged]
            ,(
                SELECT SUM([StateChanged])
                FROM StateChange ST2
                WHERE ST2.Item = ST1.Item AND ST2.RowNr <= ST1.RowNr
             ) AS GroupID
    FROM    StateChange ST1
), StateChangeRanked
AS
(
    SELECT   [Item]
            ,[EventDate]
            ,[Event]
            ,[StateChanged]
            ,[GroupID]
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Item], GroupID, [Event] ORDER BY [EventDate]) AS TransitionRank
    FROM    StateChangeGrouping
)
SELECT      [Item]
            ,MIN([EventDate]) AS [Start]
            ,MAX([EventDate]) AS [End]
            ,[GroupID]
FROM        StateChangeRanked
WHERE       GroupID > 0 AND TransitionRank = 1
GROUP BY    [Item], GroupID
ORDER BY    [Item], [Start]
```

Comment: Sorry, should have specified it needed to work with 2008.  However, this is good to know the when requirements get moved to higher version.

Comment: @brussell, dude you really need to think about upgrading :). I have added an example that should work for SQL Server 2008. I don't actually have a copy of 2008 anymore to test it so no promises.

Comment: yes, I know, but I'm bound to a product that's been out for awhile so it has to be backward compat to 2008.  This worked like a charm!  Now, I just need to try to understand how you did it! :-) -Thanks!

Comment: tried both (2012 and 2008 scripts) for performance comparision on 870 rows using our table/fields:  2012: < 1 sec, 2008: 38 seconds.  Any recommendations on indexing the table to improve the 2008 query?

Comment: @brussell unfortunately, a lot of the performance difference you are seeing is due to the optimization that comes with the Windowing functions. This includes an in-memory spool worktable that allows SQL Server to retrieve preceding rows without the need to perform self joins or correlated scalar queries as is the case with the 2008 version implementation.  
You could load the first part of the CTE where the row numbers are calculated into a temp table with an index on Item and RowNr (clustered) then execute the rest of the query against the temp table that should improve performance.

Comment: @brussell simply adding a clustered index on item and event date without any query modification will significantly help as well.

Comment: Edmond, just realized I incorrectly defined this problem.  Initially I said need to capture the last Off state, but for correct runtime it should actually be the first off state so that calc runtime is correct.  See first line of output corrected.  I've actually been testing using the 2012 version since it is faster.

Comment: @brussell this should be easy to fix. Will add update shortly.

Comment: Edmond, you have no idea how long I've been banging my head on this.  You saved me again.  Thank you sir!