# Manipulate Login Logout data with T-SQL in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Does anyone know the way of building table 2 with information in table 1? It is easy to approach with Python because I can use ‘checking by row’. However, there is a big dataset at the back so if I could conduct the data transformation with SQL language in SQL Server it will be nice. Notice that this is not a real login and logout data structure/problem, and I just want to know how to transform data in table 2 into table 1. It has the similar structure with the data I have right now but for other use.

Details: When the user first logs in to my system, I write down the time with ‘LoginTime’ in table 2. He might login to my system for several times but I will only record the very first time when he login. When he first logout of my system, I will record the ‘Eventtime’ from table 1 as ‘LogoutTime’ in table 2. If the same user doesn’t logout, I will keep the LogoutTime as ‘NULL’.

Table 1

```
UserID  EventTime   Event
1   9/1/13 15:33    0
1   9/1/13 17:00    0
1   9/1/13 18:00    0
1   9/1/13 18:20    1
1   9/1/13 18:30    1
1   9/2/13 11:05    0
1   9/2/13 11:45    1
1   9/2/13 13:50    0
2   9/1/13 16:15    0
2   9/1/13 17:00    1
2   9/1/13 18:01    0
2   9/1/13 18:02    0
2   9/1/13 19:02    1
3   9/1/13 17:10    0
3   9/1/13 19:10    1
3   9/2/13 21:01    0
```

Table 2

```
UserID  LoginTime   LogoutTime
1   9/1/13 15:33    9/1/13 18:20
1   9/2/13 11:05    9/2/13 11:45
1   9/2/13 13:50    NULL
2   9/1/13 16:15    9/1/13 17:00
2   9/1/13 18:02    9/1/13 19:02
3   9/1/13 17:10    9/1/13 19:10
3   9/1/13 21:01    NULL
```

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49950393/capture-start-and-end-times-for-changes-of-state-of-a-field/49952071#49952071) question is vaguely related.

Comment: What happens on 9/2/13? Do you want one record per day per user? Are you sure the first record should be 18:20 and not 18:30 ? (the second logout). This login/logout process has a lot of edge cases that you need to consider

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid check my solution, it explain by simply solving the issue according to the OP request: "`When he first logout of my system...`". According to the request we need to use the FIRST login or the FIRST logout (unless the OP will change the question's description).

Comment: In my experience with these types of login/logouts, I don't think the OP has explained the full problem or considered the edge cases

Comment: I totally agree. My first reaction was to write comment about this with examples but since we are using this stackoverflow awful interface, which only give me option to post one-line comment or answer, I simply posted the answer. If this question was asked in MSDN forums for example my response was totally different. It was starting with explaining that `this requirement implies a problematic design of the system, and I already can imagine the bugs that will follow it`. But yet, I will provide the same answer as this solve the current request (I still have my original respond ready in Notepad)

Comment: stackoverflow has a very poor interface in my opinion, which I really hate, but there is `awesome community` here which covers the lack of a good interface. The community and the fact that people are very active here, is what makes stackoverflow successful, while the interface is very poor in my opinion.

Comment: Apologize for my poor explanation. Your answer solved my problem. I will test them today and post follow-ups.  @Ronen Ariely

Comment: That's OK. No one born an expert and we all learn all the time. Next time you can do better. The problem is that your design is problematic and not just the way you asked the question or the missing information. Using this design you will probably encounter in future issues in real life scenario. Thinks for example about case that you miss a login (a user forgot to login) or a logout. You have no relations between the login row to the logout row which mean you cannot say which logout is really related to which login. You only count on the time and the order of the tasks you stored in the table

Comment: Using this design you should at ;east cover all the cases and choose what you will do in each case. Simply selecting the first login or the first logout is a way to go but this way will lead to dramatic issues. For example employee login at 2018-02-27 and forgot logout since he have a birthday. He come back after a short vacation and his next login is in 2018-03-01. and the end of that day he logout. Do you want to pay this use for all the time between his first login and the logout several days after?!?

Comment: As I mentioned, this interface dose not fit for tech discussion IMO and I cannot represent examples (formatted code) in the comments. But In short, I gave you the answer to the question and we can close the thread, but you should re-think about your entire system design. or at least cover all extreme cases and choose what you want to do in each case :-)

Comment: Actually, I am not dealing with a login and logout database. I am dealing with a database which record whether a program of an organization is put in the market or not. So I want to know the start time point of this program in the market and the end time point of getting this program off the market. This login and logout table is from a website where people show case their solutions for other kinds of data transformation. My goal of using this login and logout table is to protect the original data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day,

#### DDL+DML: Something the user that ask the question should post!!!

```
-- I assume that your date and time data is in format "mm/dd/yy", which means style 1
-- For better aqurecy I am using datetime2(7) 
drop table if exists T;
create table T(UserID int, EventTime datetime2(7), [Event] bit)
GO
INSERT T(UserID,EventTime,Event)
values
(1,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/1/13 15:33', 1), 0),
(1,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/1/13 17:00', 1), 0),
(1,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/1/13 18:00', 1), 0),
(1,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/1/13 18:20', 1), 1),
(1,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/1/13 18:30', 1), 1),
(1,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/2/13 11:05', 1), 0),
(1,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/2/13 11:45', 1), 1),
(1,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/2/13 13:50', 1), 0),
(2,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/1/13 16:15', 1), 0),
(2,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/1/13 17:00', 1), 1),
(2,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/1/13 18:01', 1), 0),
(2,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/1/13 18:02', 1), 0),
(2,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/1/13 19:02', 1), 1),
(3,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/1/13 17:10', 1), 0),
(3,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/1/13 19:10', 1), 1),
(3,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/2/13 21:01', 1), 0)
GO
SELECT * FROM T
order by UserID, EventTime, Event
GO
```

#### First draft of solution

Please check if this solve your needs

```
;with MyCTE as (
    SELECT UserID, EventTime, [Event]
        , [RN1-RN2] = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by UserID, EventTime, [Event]) - ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by UserID, [Event] order by UserID, EventTime, [Event])
    FROM T
),
MyCTE2 as (
    select distinct UserID, [Event] 
        , MIN(EventTime) OVER (partition by UserID,[Event], [RN1-RN2]) M
    from MyCTE
)
select UserID
  , [0] as LoginTime
  , [1] as LogoutTime
From (
    select UserID, [Event], M
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by UserID,[Event] order by M) as GroupNum
    from MyCTE2
)x
pivot
(
  MIN(M)
  for [Event] in([0], [1])
)p
order by UserID, [LoginTime]
GO
```

If this solution fits you then we know that I got your needs, and we can move to the next step which is discuss about performance. For this we will need to get your real tab;e structure ans some more sample data (DDL+DML from you)

Comment: This answer works for my problem. Thank you! Notice that this is a fake data and the problem might not make sense for real login and logout data management. I am using data with similar structure and want to know the time range of a promotion put in the market.

Comment: You are most welcome;-) I glad I could help. Have a great day Helen