# How to create table showing program start and end date with weekly program status table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Could anybody kindly help me with the problem as follows using T-SQL in SQL Server?

My original table shows a company's program weekly status: whether the program is in or off the market. The table structure is as follows:

```
ProgramID Status Sunday
1         1      1/3/2016
1         1      1/10/2016
1         0      1/17/2016
1         1      1/24/2016
2         0      1/3/2016
2         1      1/10/2016
2         1      1/17/2016
2         0      1/24/2016
```

I want to create a table as following. When the ProgramID 1 is put into the market, I take the record done with line 1 `(Program ID = 1, StartSunday = 1/3/2016, EndSaturday = NULL`). Then, Program 1 is taken off the market on 1/17/2016. So, I fill EndSaturday in line one with value '1/16/2016'. When ProgramID 2 is not in the market I don't start to record it (Notice that I have ProgramID = 2   Status = 0   Sunday = 1/3/2016). When ProgramID 2 is first put into the market on 1/10/2016, I start to take done the record as what we did for ProgramID 1 (ProgramID = 1, StartSunday = 1/10/2016, EndSaturday = Null). When the program is take off the market on 1/24/2016, I renew the record in line 3 with ProgramID = 2, StartSunday = 1/10/2016, EndSaturday = 1/23/2016.

```
ProgramID   StartSunday   EndSaturday
1           1/3/2016      1/16/2016
1           1/24/2016     NULL
2           1/10/2016     1/23/2016
```

This problem is the same as the post: [Manipulate Login Logout data with T-SQL in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51621694/manipulate-login-logout-data-with-t-sql-in-sql-server)

However, my data has one more line: (1,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/1/13 15:00', 1), 1), which means some program are not in the system at the beginning. Then, the code doesn't work anymore.

drop table if exists T;

create table T(UserID int, EventTime datetime2(7), [Event] bit)

GO

INSERT T(UserID,EventTime,Event)

values

(1,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/1/13 15:00', 1), 1),

(1,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/1/13 15:33', 1), 0),

(1,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/1/13 17:00', 1), 0),

(1,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/1/13 18:00', 1), 0),

(1,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/1/13 18:20', 1), 1),

(1,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/1/13 18:30', 1), 1),

(1,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/2/13 11:05', 1), 0),

(1,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/2/13 11:45', 1), 1),

(1,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/2/13 13:50', 1), 0),

(2,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/1/13 16:15', 1), 0),

(2,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/1/13 17:00', 1), 1),

(2,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/1/13 18:01', 1), 0),

(2,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/1/13 18:02', 1), 0),

(2,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/1/13 19:02', 1), 1),

(3,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/1/13 15:10', 1), 1),

(3,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/1/13 17:10', 1), 0),

(3,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/1/13 19:10', 1), 1),

(3,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'9/2/13 21:01', 1), 0)

GO

SELECT * FROM T

order by UserID, EventTime, Event

GO

Comment: If you would post your code and a _specific_ problem we could help. Otherwise, it looks like you've posted a request for Free Contract Programming. Perhaps a solution related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51621694/manipulate-login-logout-data-with-t-sql-in-sql-server) question is possible.

Comment: @HelenZhang - I suggest you update your question to better display code blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This as a query or view would do it:

```
select p.ProgramID, min(p.sunday) as StartSunday, dateadd(d,-1,p2.sunday) as EndSaturday 
from prog p
join prog p2 on p2.ProgramID=p.ProgramID and p2.status=0 and p2.sunday>p.sunday
and not exists(select * from prog p3 where p3.ProgramID=p.ProgramID and p3.status=0 and p3.sunday>p.sunday and p3.sunday<p2.sunday)
where p.status=1
group by p.programID, p2.Sunday
union
select ProgramID, Sunday, null 
from prog p
where status=1 
and not exists(select * from prog p2  where p2.ProgramID=p.ProgramID and p2.status=0 and p2.sunday>p.sunday)
```

Answer (score 0):

Code for creating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE MarketRecord (  
    ProductID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,  
    Status BIT DEFAULT(0),  
    StartDate DATE NOT NULL  
    EndDate DATE NOT NULL 
)
```

You would update your table and change the status of a product:

```
UPDATE MarketRecord  
SET Status = 1  
WHERE PtoductID = <some item>
```

Then, you would use a FOR UPDATE TRIGGER which would react on status change:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgChangeStatus 
ON MarketRecord 
AFTER UPDATE 
AS 

BEGIN  
    UPDATE MarketRecord  
    SET EndDate = GETDATE()  
    FROM MarketRecord  
    INNER JOIN inserted i  
        ON ProductID = i.ProductID    
END
```