# Find Start and End Dates of changed column for each id's sub-type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Another variation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637935/t-sql-start-and-end-date-times-from-a-single-column) but with an added layer of complexity due to the addition of a sub-type specific to each id.

Source:

```
id     sub-type     event_date              condition
A      A1           2011-10-03 00:00:00     Condition1
A      A1           2012-04-30 00:00:00     Condition1
A      A1           2013-09-22 00:00:00     Condition1
A      A1           2014-11-25 00:00:00     Condition2
A      A1           2015-01-01 00:00:00     Condition1 *
A      A2           2011-10-03 00:00:00     Condition3
A      A2           2012-04-31 00:00:00     Condition4
A      A2           2013-11-25 00:00:00     Condition4
A      A3           2011-10-03 00:00:00     Condition4
A      A3           2012-04-31 00:00:00     Condition4
A      A3           2013-11-25 00:00:00     Condition2
B      A1           2012-04-31 00:00:00     Condition4
B      A1           2013-11-25 00:00:00     Condition4
C      A1           2013-03-23 00:00:00     Condition1
C      A1           2014-12-25 00:00:00     Condition2
C      A1           2015-10-03 00:00:00     Condition3
C      A1           2016-06-26 00:00:00     Condition3
C      A1           2017-08-07 00:00:00     Condition4
C      A2           2015-10-03 00:00:00     Condition4
C      A2           2017-08-07 00:00:00     Condition1
```

Expected Output:

```
id     sub-type     event_date_start        event_date_end        condition
A      A1           2011-10-03 00:00:00     2013-09-22 00:00:00   Condition1
A      A1           2014-11-25 00:00:00     2014-11-25 00:00:00   Condition2
A      A1           2014-11-25 00:00:00     2015-01-01 00:00:00   Condition1 *
A      A2           2011-10-03 00:00:00     2011-10-03 00:00:00   Condition3
A      A2           2012-04-31 00:00:00     2013-11-25 00:00:00   Condition4
A      A3           2011-10-03 00:00:00     2012-04-31 00:00:00   Condition4
A      A3           2013-11-25 00:00:00     2013-11-25 00:00:00   Condition2
B      A1           2012-04-31 00:00:00     2013-11-25 00:00:00   Condition4
C      A1           2013-03-23 00:00:00     2013-03-23 00:00:00   Condition1
C      A1           2014-12-25 00:00:00     2014-12-25 00:00:00   Condition2
C      A1           2015-10-03 00:00:00     2016-06-26 00:00:00   Condition3
C      A1           2017-08-07 00:00:00     2017-08-07 00:00:00   Condition4
C      A2           2015-10-03 00:00:00     2015-10-03 00:00:00   Condition4
C      A2           2017-08-07 00:00:00     2017-08-07 00:00:00   Condition1
```

*Edit:  Added row where the condition could return to a previous condition later.  Thank you [@squirell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/185647/squirrel)

Comment: Will you have situation like for example `A - A1 - 2015-01-01 - Condition1`?

Comment: Yes a situation like that could occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with cte as
(select id,subtype,event_date,condition, 
  row_number()over(partition by id, subtype order by event_date)rn,
  case when condition<>lag(condition)over (partition by id, subtype order by event_date) then 1 else 0 end as d
from events 
)
, finalCte as
(select *,sum(d)over(partition by id,subtype order by rn)grp from cte 
)
select id,subtype,min(event_date)event_date_start,max(event_date)event_date_End,condition
from finalCte
Group by id,subtype,condition,grp
order by id,subtype,max(rn)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ce45a/1/0

Comment: Is there a way I could modify the query to be able to set the event_date_end as the event_date_start from the subsequent row?  Example output of first row would be: 

A      A1           2011-10-03 00:00:00     2014-11-25 00:00:00    Condition1

Comment: Yes you surely can do that. I have added another answer. At the last row since there is no leading row the actual end_date will be the end date.

Answer (score 3):

You can use simple aggregation with group by for that.

Query:

```
select id,sub_type,min(event_date) event_date_start,
   max(event_date) event_end_start,[condition] from events
group by id,sub_type,[condition]
```

OUtput:

| id | sub_type | event_date_start | event_end_start | condition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | 2011-10-03 00:00:00.000 | 2013-09-22 00:00:00.000 | Condition1 |
| A | A1 | 2014-11-25 00:00:00.000 | 2014-11-25 00:00:00.000 | Condition2 |
| A | A2 | 2011-10-03 00:00:00.000 | 2011-10-03 00:00:00.000 | Condition3 |
| A | A2 | 2012-04-30 00:00:00.000 | 2013-11-25 00:00:00.000 | Condition4 |
| A | A3 | 2013-11-25 00:00:00.000 | 2013-11-25 00:00:00.000 | Condition2 |
| A | A3 | 2011-10-03 00:00:00.000 | 2012-04-30 00:00:00.000 | Condition4 |
| B | A1 | 2012-04-30 00:00:00.000 | 2013-11-25 00:00:00.000 | Condition4 |
| C | A1 | 2013-03-23 00:00:00.000 | 2013-03-23 00:00:00.000 | Condition1 |
| C | A1 | 2014-12-25 00:00:00.000 | 2014-12-25 00:00:00.000 | Condition2 |
| C | A1 | 2015-10-03 00:00:00.000 | 2016-06-26 00:00:00.000 | Condition3 |
| C | A1 | 2017-08-07 00:00:00.000 | 2017-08-07 00:00:00.000 | Condition4 |
| C | A2 | 2017-08-07 00:00:00.000 | 2017-08-07 00:00:00.000 | Condition1 |
| C | A2 | 2015-10-03 00:00:00.000 | 2015-10-03 00:00:00.000 | Condition4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uaCGY4Ew)

Comment: Made it too complex without any reason.

Comment: This is the actual structure of a query I was attempting to write.  I marked your answer as correct.  This was perfect.  Thank you!

Comment: I think there is a case where this query doesn't work.  If a condition returns to a previous state later, this query spans between the entire dates for that sub-type regardless of the dates in between.  I added an edit in my original question.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is entirely a new problem. Please explain why event_start_date is `2014-11-25 00:00:00` for the second occurrence of condition1.

Comment: @skyliner33v I have added another answer. Please check.

Comment: My apologies.  I thought I captured this case in the data.  I appreciate your help and have marked your other submission as the answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the grouping of the consecutive rows. First use `lag()` window function to check for change in `condition`, then use window function to perform the cumulative `sum()`. The sum is the `grouping` (`grp`) required.

Final query is a group by query

```
with 
cte as
(
    select e.id, e.sub_type, e.event_date, e.[condition],
           f = case when e.[condition] 
                    <>   lag(e.[condition]) over (partition by e.id, e.sub_type 
                                                      order by event_date)
                    then 1 -- change in condition
                    else 0 -- no change
                    end
    from   events e
),
cte2 as
(
    select id, sub_type, event_date, [condition],
           -- the grouping to identify required consecutive rows
           grp = sum(f) over (partition by id, sub_type 
                                  order by event_date)
    from   cte
)
select id, sub_type,
       event_date_start = min(event_date),
       event_date_end   = max(event_date),
       [condition]
from   cte2 c
group by id, sub_type, condition, grp
order by id, sub_type, event_date_start
```

Result:

| id | sub_type | event_date_start | event_date_end | condition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | 2011-10-03 | 2013-09-22 | Condition1 |
| A | A1 | 2014-11-25 | 2014-11-25 | Condition2 |
| A | A1 | 2015-01-01 | 2015-01-01 | Condition1 |
| A | A2 | 2011-10-03 | 2011-10-03 | Condition3 |
| A | A2 | 2012-04-30 | 2013-11-25 | Condition4 |
| A | A3 | 2011-10-03 | 2012-04-30 | Condition4 |
| A | A3 | 2013-11-25 | 2013-11-25 | Condition2 |
| B | A1 | 2012-04-30 | 2013-11-25 | Condition4 |
| C | A1 | 2013-03-23 | 2013-03-23 | Condition1 |
| C | A1 | 2014-12-25 | 2014-12-25 | Condition2 |
| C | A1 | 2015-10-03 | 2016-06-26 | Condition3 |
| C | A1 | 2017-08-07 | 2017-08-07 | Condition4 |
| C | A2 | 2015-10-03 | 2015-10-03 | Condition4 |
| C | A2 | 2017-08-07 | 2017-08-07 | Condition1 |

Note : When posting here please do check that your sample data is valid. There isn't 31 days for the month of April.

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/PHKPDMIj)

Comment: Thank you!  And I apologize for the mistake.  I hand changed some of the values and just starting running random numbers in.

Comment: Is there a way I could modify the query to be able to set the event_date_end as the event_date_start from the subsequent row? Example output of first row would be: A A1 2011-10-03 00:00:00 2014-11-25 00:00:00 Condition1

Comment: Don't quite understand  your requirement. It is best you ask this as a new question. Remember to include the sample data and expected result and the query that you used

Answer (score 0):

you can use cte and get max event_date with Row_number

```
;with _list as
(
  select 
            id
           ,[sub-type]
           ,event_date
           ,condition,
            row_number()over(
                               partition by id,[sub-type],[condition] 
                               order by event_date desc
                            )rw,
            max(event_date)over(
                                 partition by id,[sub-type],[condition] 
                                 order by event_date desc
                                ) maxevent_date
  FROM dd
)
SELECT 
          id,
          [sub-type]
          ,event_date as event_date_start
          , maxevent_date as event_end_start
          ,rw
          ,condition

  FROM _list a
  WHERE rw=1
  ORDER BY a.id,a.[sub-type],a.condition
```

You can insert Base data  with the following statements:

```
drop TABLE if exists  dd
CREATE TABLE dd (  id VARCHAR(1), [sub-type] VARCHAR(2), event_date DATETIME, condition VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO dd (id, [sub-type], event_date, condition) VALUES ('A', 'A1', '2011-10-03 00:00:00', 'Condition1')
INSERT INTO dd (id, [sub-type], event_date, condition) VALUES ('A', 'A1', '2012-04-30 00:00:00', 'Condition1')
INSERT INTO dd (id, [sub-type], event_date, condition) VALUES ('A', 'A1', '2013-09-22 00:00:00', 'Condition1')
INSERT INTO dd (id, [sub-type], event_date, condition) VALUES ('A', 'A1', '2014-11-25 00:00:00', 'Condition2')
INSERT INTO dd (id, [sub-type], event_date, condition) VALUES ('A', 'A2', '2011-10-03 00:00:00', 'Condition3')
INSERT INTO dd (id, [sub-type], event_date, condition) VALUES ('A', 'A2', '2012-04-30 00:00:00', 'Condition4')
INSERT INTO dd (id, [sub-type], event_date, condition) VALUES ('A', 'A2', '2013-11-25 00:00:00', 'Condition4')
INSERT INTO dd (id, [sub-type], event_date, condition) VALUES ('A', 'A3', '2011-10-03 00:00:00', 'Condition4')
INSERT INTO dd (id, [sub-type], event_date, condition) VALUES ('A', 'A3', '2012-04-30 00:00:00', 'Condition4')
INSERT INTO dd (id, [sub-type], event_date, condition) VALUES ('A', 'A3', '2013-11-25 00:00:00', 'Condition2')
INSERT INTO dd (id, [sub-type], event_date, condition) VALUES ('B', 'A1', '2012-04-30 00:00:00', 'Condition4')
INSERT INTO dd (id, [sub-type], event_date, condition) VALUES ('B', 'A1', '2013-11-25 00:00:00', 'Condition4')
INSERT INTO dd (id, [sub-type], event_date, condition) VALUES ('C', 'A1', '2013-03-23 00:00:00', 'Condition1')
INSERT INTO dd (id, [sub-type], event_date, condition) VALUES ('C', 'A1', '2014-12-25 00:00:00', 'Condition2')
INSERT INTO dd (id, [sub-type], event_date, condition) VALUES ('C', 'A1', '2015-10-03 00:00:00', 'Condition3')
INSERT INTO dd (id, [sub-type], event_date, condition) VALUES ('C', 'A1', '2016-06-26 00:00:00', 'Condition3')
INSERT INTO dd (id, [sub-type], event_date, condition) VALUES ('C', 'A1', '2017-08-07 00:00:00', 'Condition4')
INSERT INTO dd (id, [sub-type], event_date, condition) VALUES ('C', 'A2', '2015-10-03 00:00:00', 'Condition4')
INSERT INTO dd (id, [sub-type], event_date, condition) VALUES ('C', 'A2', '2017-08-07 00:00:00', 'Condition1')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
with cte as
(select id,subtype,event_date,condition, 
  row_number()over(partition by id, subtype order by event_date)rn,
  case when condition<>lag(condition)over (partition by id, subtype order by event_date) then 1 else 0 end as d
from events 
)
, finalCte as
(select *,sum(d)over(partition by id,subtype order by rn)grp from cte 
)
select id,subtype,min(event_date)event_date_start,COALESCE(lead(min(event_date))over(order by id,subtype,max(rn)),max(event_date))event_date_End,condition
from finalCte
Group by id,subtype,condition,grp
order by id,subtype,max(rn)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ce45a/7